# Why Tomcat gives error when importing a plain object?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, jetty, tomcat8

Tomcat 8.5.35 gives a strange error when trying to initialize a simple object inside a JSP page.

Here is the error:

[image]

and here is the JSP:

```
<%@page import="dust.One"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <%
            One o = new One("Joe");
            out.println(o.getName());
        %>      
    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the class

```java
package dust;

public class One {
    String name;

    public One(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }        
}
```

I have to mention that the same webapp is working just fine in Jetty (9.4.35).

What can it be?

--Edit--
It seems that if the app is packed as .war and deployed on Tomcat through it's Manager web interface it's working fine.

Comment: You say it's working with Jetty and if you deploy with Tomcat's manager interface. Does that mean it's not working with the Tomcat plugin in your IDE? Try a project clean and a rebuild, then a publish on tomcat so that it synchronizes with your latest version. Sometimes, with hot deploys, or redeploys, not everything gets published or synchronized properly and you might end up with different class versions. A clean, rebuild, redeploy normally fixes the issue, meaning that it's not necessarily a Tomcat problem, but a Tomcat IDE plugin problem.

Comment: @Bogdan That was indeed the problem. After an upgrade of Netbeans (and consequently of the plugin) all worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem vanished with the upgrade of Netbeans to version 13.

As @Bogdan mentioned I think this comes more from Netbeans plugins than from the Tomcat itself.